# rmarkdown render not recognizing parameters

Tags: r, r-markdown

In my R file I have:

```
library(rmarkdown)

rmarkdown::render("C://Users//me//Desktop//test_param.Rmd", 
                  params = list(region = "west"))
```

and in the rmd file:

````
---
title: "test"
output: pdf_document
params:
  name: "test"
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

`r params$name`
````

that rmd works when I run in separately.

BUT when I run the .r file I get this error

```
Error in knit_params_get(input_lines, params) : 
  render params not declared in YAML: region
```

what's the reason for this error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`knitr`'s override overrides *existing* params. You need to have a front matter like:

```
---
title: "test"
output: pdf_document
params:
  name: "test"
  region: ""
---
```

Comment: Ohh I think I had a typo I should have had name instead of region in the call

Comment: Most typo questions get closed, but I recommend leaving this open as I wasn't able to find a similar problem in the search and it's a conceivable problem that someone could have.

Comment: thanks for leaving this open. I've just noticed that is the datatype in the original YAML mismatches the datatype in the overriding YAML, then it won't override.